# How to hide all interactions with the bot and show only final result in Element Web Messenger?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, open-source

I play with Matrix Element Web Messenger, there is a bot in GitHub (mautrix/whatsapp) that allows connecting Whatsapp. I want to make it so that instead of the usual interaction with the bot (create a room, send a "login" message, get a QR to connect), the user simply clicks on a button and a window with a QR code opens. Can anyone suggest to me how to automate these steps? I've been struggling with this for two weeks now!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use an API. There are a few libraries available that you can use to integrate Whatsapp with Matrix Element Web Messenger, such as the mautrix-whatsapp library. This library provides an API that can be used to automate the steps of connecting a Whatsapp bot to Matrix Element Web Messenger. It also provides a command line interface (CLI) to make the process even easier. Additionally, you can use the mautrix-whatsapp-js library to create a custom button that will open a window with a QR code for the user to scan. This library has detailed instructions for how to use it to create a custom button.